# Abrupt increase in animation delay on repeatedly activating click event. Keeps on increasing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a custom side navigation menu that slides into place after clicking on the burger menu and then slides back off-screen after clicking on the translucent black layer(below random content).

It works fine the first time I click on the burger menu and close it, but if I repeatedly perform this(after 6-7 times its quite prominent), the slide-in time(animation) increases and keeps on increasing there on.

This problem is simulated in the fiddle below.

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/landstrider/wnz54t28/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <div class="slide-tabs">
   <a href="">A</a>
   <a href="">B</a>
  </div>
</div>

/***** header ******/
<div class="header">
  <div class="sidenav-burger-menu d-sm-none d-flex">
    <div class="sidenav-toggle">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar bar1"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar bar2"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar bar3"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

/***** random content *****/
<div class="overflow-wrapper">
  <div class="overflow-wrapper-overlay d-none"></div>
  <div class="main-content"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
/***** sidenav styles *****/

 .sidenav {
   height: 100vh;
   width: 250px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 3;
   top: 0;
   left: -250px;
   background-color: #111;
   overflow-x: hidden;
  }


 /***** header styles *****/

 .header {
  background-color: black;
  .sidenav-burger-menu {
   .sidenav-toggle {
    .icon-bar {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      width: 24px;
      height: 2px;
      border-radius: 1px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      & + .icon-bar {
       margin-top: 4px;
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

.overflow-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
 .overflow-wrapper-overlay {
   position: absolute;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .main-content {
  height: 100vh;
 }
}
```

**Javascript(JQuery)**

```
/***** sidenav script *****/
var count = 0;

$('.sidenav-burger-menu').on('click', function() {
 var sidenav = $('div.sidenav');
 var overflow_wrapper = $('.overflow-wrapper');
 var overflow_wrapper_overlay = $('.overflow-wrapper .overflow-wrapper-overlay');
 if (sidenav.position().left === -250) {
  $('html, body').css({
   'overflow': 'hidden'
  });
  sidenav.animate({
   'left': 0
  }, 200);
  overflow_wrapper.animate({
   'left': 250
  }, 200);
  overflow_wrapper_overlay.removeClass('d-none');
  if (count === 0) {
   overflow_wrapper_overlay.css('z-index', '99');
   count += 1;
  }
  overflow_wrapper_overlay.on('click', function() {
   sidenav.animate({
    'left': -250
   }, 200);
  overflow_wrapper.animate({
    'left': 0
  }, 200);
  setTimeout(function() {
   overflow_wrapper_overlay.addClass('d-none');
   $('html, body').css({
     'overflow': 'unset'
   });
   }, 200);
  })
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why you're seeing this behavior in the code as written, but I suspect it has something to do with you defining multiple click handlers on the overflow element every time the hamburger menu is clicked.

Regardless, it would be simpler for this use case to just use CSS transitions and let jQuery manage a simple CSS state toggle.

Demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yzpxvzgy/

1. Add to your `.sidenav` CSS:

   ```
   transition-property: left;
   transition-duration: .2s;
   ```
2. Add a new CSS rule:

   ```
   .sidenav.display {
     left: 0;
   }
   ```
3. Replace your jQuery with the code below, that simply toggles the `display` class on the sidenav, and removes it if clicking the overlay:

   ```
   var sidenav = $('div.sidenav');
   $('.overflow-wrapper .overflow-wrapper-overlay').on('click', function() {
     sidenav.removeClass('display');
   });
   $('.sidenav-burger-menu').on('click', function() {
     sidenav.toggleClass('display');
   });
   ```

I didn't do anything with your `z-index` variations, but it may be that you can simply define the z-index appropriately in your CSS rather than varying it by number of times the menu has been clicked.